# compact(): Undefined variable $pesanan_details

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

My error

compact(): Undefined variable $pesanan_details

Line 138 experienced an error and a red notification on that line

```
return view('checkout.check_out', compact('pesanan','pesanan_details'));
```

Controller `controller/PesananController`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Pesanan;
use App\Models\Post;
use App\Models\PesananDetail;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\StorePesananRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\UpdatePesananRequest;

class PesananController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $post = post::where('id', $id)->first();
        return view('pesan.index', compact('barang'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     */
    public function store(StorePesananRequest $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     */
    public function show(Pesanan $pesanan)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     */
    public function edit(Pesanan $pesanan)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     */
    public function update(UpdatePesananRequest $request, Pesanan $pesanan)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     */
    public function destroy(Pesanan $pesanan)
    {
        //
    }

    public function pesan(Request $request, $id)
    {
        // dd($request);
        $post = Post::where('id', $id)->first();

        // cek validasi pesanan melebihi stok
        // if($request->jumlah_pesan > $post->stok)
        // {
        //     return redirect("/post")->with('No', 'Stok Kurang Dari Pesanan Anda');
        // }
        // cek validasi pesanan
        $cek_pesanan = Pesanan::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->where('status',0)->first();
        // simpan  ke pesanan
        if(empty($cek_pesanan))
        {
            $pesanan = new Pesanan;
            $pesanan->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
            $pesanan->status = 0;
            $pesanan->jumlah_harga = 0;
            $pesanan->save();
        }

        $pesanan_baru = Pesanan::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->where('status',0)->first();

        // cek pesanan_detail
        $cek_pesanan_detail = PesananDetail::where('post_id', $post->id)->where('pesanan_id', $pesanan_baru->id)->first();
        if(empty($cek_pesanan_detail))
        {
            $pesanan_detail = new PesananDetail;
            $pesanan_detail->post_id = $post->id;
            $pesanan_detail->pesanan_id = $pesanan_baru->id;
            $pesanan_detail->jumlah = $request->jumlah_pesan;
            $pesanan_detail->jumlah_harga = $post->harga*$request->jumlah_pesan;
            $pesanan_detail->save();
        }else
        {
        $pesanan_detail = PesananDetail::where('post_id', $post->id)->where('pesanan_id', $pesanan_baru->id)->first();
        $pesanan_detail->jumlah = $pesanan_detail->jumlah+$request->jumlah_pesan;

        // harga sekarang setelah update
        $harga_pesanan_detail_baru = $post->harga*$request->jumlah_pesan;
        $pesanan_detail->jumlah_harga = $pesanan_detail->jumlah_harga+$harga_pesanan_detail_baru;
        $pesanan_detail->update();
        }
        // jumlah total
        $pesanan = Pesanan::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->where('status',0)->first();
        $pesanan->jumlah_harga =  $pesanan->jumlah_harga+$post->harga*$request->jumlah_pesan;
        $pesanan->update();

            return redirect('home');
        }

        public function check_out()
        {
            $pesanan = Pesanan::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->where('status',0)->first();
        if(!empty($pesanan))
        {
            $pesanan_details = PesananDetail::where('pesanan_id', $pesanan->id)->get();
        }

        return view('checkout.check_out', compact('pesanan','pesanan_details'));
        }

        public function delete($id)
        {
            $pesanan_detail = PesananDetail::where('id', $id)->first();

            $pesanan = Pesanan::where('id', $pesanan_detail->pesanan_id)->first();
            $pesanan->jumlah_harga = $pesanan->jumlah_harga-$pesanan_detail->jumlah_harga;
            $pesanan->update();

            $pesanan_detail->delete();
            // Allert::error('Pesanan Sukses Dihapus', 'Hapus');
            return redirect('check-out');
        }
        public function konfirmasi()
        {
            $pesanan = Pesanan::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->where('status',0)->first();
            $pesanan->status = 1;
            $pesanan->update();

            return redirect('check-out');
        }
    }
```

Views `check_out.blade.php`:

```
{{-- @dd($posts) --}}
@extends('layouts.main')
@section('container')
    <div class="container">
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/feather-icons"></script>

        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h3><i class="me-2" data-feather="shopping-cart"></i>Check Out</h3>
                        @if(!empty($pesanan))
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <table class="table table-bordered">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>No</th>
                                    <th>Nama Barang</th>
                                    <th>Jumlah</th>
                                    <th>Harga</th>
                                    <th>Total Harga</th>
                                    <th>Aksi</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <?php $no = 1; ?>
                                @foreach ($pesanan_details as $pesanan_detail )
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{ $no++ }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $pesanan_detail->post->title }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $pesanan_detail->jumlah }} Style</td>
                                    <td align="left">Rp. {{ number_format($pesanan_detail->post->harga) }}</td>
                                    <td align="left">Rp. {{ $pesanan_detail->jumlah_harga }}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <form action="{{ url('check-out')}}/{{ $pesanan_detail->id }}" method="post">
                                            @csrf
                                            {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i data-feather="trash-2"></i></button>
                                        </form>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                @endforeach
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="4" align="center"><strong>Total Harga :</strong></td>
                                    <td><strong>Rp. {{ number_format($pesanan->jumlah_harga) }}</strong></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href="{{ url('konfirmasi-check-out') }}" class="btn btn-success">
                                        <i data-feather="shopping-cart"></i>Check Out
                                        </a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {{-- <button type="submit" href="/home" class="btn btn-primary mt-3">Kembali</button> --}}
            <a href="/home" class="d-block mt-3 text-decoration-none">Kembali</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
@endsection
```

Comment: in your if clause, you only declare if, nothing else, and program skipping if when false, so you dont have variable $pemesanan_details , and some tips for you, dont just copy paste all the code, analyst and specify the scope of problem

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because `$pesanan` is empty so the program doesn't read inside `if (!empty($pesanan)` and `$pesanan_details` becomes `undefined` because you don't declare it anywhere except that statement. Please make sure you have data in `$pesanan` or you need to handle if `$pesanan` also empty. Maybe in `else` statement like `$pesanan_details = null;`

Semoga membantu bang

Comment: @DaffanaufasSetiawan okido, does it works?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `check_out controller`, before the if you most define your variable as null. it's because if your if returns `false`, the variable defined before and you compact will work okay, but else, the variable is not define and returns to you this error.

###### resolved code:

```
public function check_out(){
        $pesanan = Pesanan::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->where('status',0)->first();
        $pesanan_details = null;
        if(!empty($pesanan))
        {
            $pesanan_details = PesananDetail::where('pesanan_id', $pesanan->id)->get();
        }

        return view('checkout.check_out',compact('pesanan','pesanan_details'));
}
```